# Silverlight 5 ,Prism 5.1 StaticResource Use Not working of static class

Tags: wpf, mvvm, silverlight-5.0, prism-4

I am unable to understand a thing which is as follows. My project is in Prism 4.1 Sliverlight 5. I'm Using MVVM pattern. 
I've a static class like this

```
{
    public static class RegionNames 
   {
     public static string AUTH_LOGIN_REGION = "AuthRegion";
     public static string TAB_TEST_REGION = "TabRegion";
     public static string USER_TAB_REGION="UserTabRegion";
    }
}
```

I tried to use this class in Shell.xmal like below.

```
    <Grid.Resources>            
        <inf:RegionNames x:Key="rName"></inf:RegionNames>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Now this Resource I used in textblock
Result :**No text appeared.**

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource rNamee}, Path=USER_TAB_REGION}" Margin="20"></TextBlock>
```

Now I changed this class like below:

```
{
    public class RegionNames : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
     public static string AUTH_LOGIN_REGION = "AuthRegion";
     public static string TAB_TEST_REGION = "TabRegion";
     public static string USER_TAB_REGION="UserTabRegion";

    public RegionNames() {
        AuthReginName = "HOLY COW POW POW !!";
    }

    private string _authReginName;
    public string AuthReginName {
        get {
            return _authReginName;
        }
        set {
            _authReginName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AuthReginName");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And used it like this

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource rNamee}, Path=AuthReginName}"></TextBlock>
```

Result : **Text Appeared**

this time it worked. Why? My static defied string values are not coming?. 
Is there any relation with Object creation of class & Setting Properties values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **for instance objects you can bind only with properties**, that's why second solution works for you. (*You can't bind with fields*)

And for **`static properties`** you can bind with fields but you need to use **`x:Static`**  markup extension. (*same goes for properties as well*)

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.USER_TAB_REGION}" Margin="20"/>
```

Comment: About x:Static it will not work like this in Silverlight 5 as it is a static class.

Answer (score 0):

My Second Question with this thread About x:Static

For Silverlight 5 who want to Use x:Static in xaml.

http://brianlagunas.com/creating-a-silverlight-5-static-markup-extension/

is Helpful & Worked for me.